# Loading data into JsonStore

Tags: data-binding, extjs, jsonstore

I'm trying to get some simple data into a JsonStore, but it doesn't seem to work. The code is pretty much the same as examples:

```
var itemListStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
   url: '/items/list',
   root: 'items',
   fields: [
      {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
      {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
   ]
});
itemListStore.load(); 
...
      items: [
      {
         xtype: 'listview',
         store: itemListStore,
         columnResize: false,
         flex: 1,
         columns: [
            {header: 'ID', dataIndex: 'id'},
            {header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name'},
         ]
      }
...
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The table loads with no rows and the count on the store is 68 (as returned by server, got via `listview.getStore().getCount()`). If I substitute JsonStore with an ArrayStore and some static data, I can see them.

The result from `/items/list` is just:

```
{"items":
    [{"id": "a", "name": "Some name"},
    {"id": "b", "name": "Some other name"}]
}
```

How do I fix this? How do I even debug this?

Edit: updated the information about record count

Comment: if from the console you Ext.getCmp('yourlistview').getStore().reload(), can you see the XHR return?

Comment: @Brandon - When I run this, I get back undefined, but a correct request is made over the network (according to firebug).

Comment: does it work if you change the xtype to grid? ;)

Comment: oh, if you are in internet explorer and have trailing commas in fields and columns it may be broken. (probably not the issue though)

Comment: @Brandon - Actually yes, it works if I use 'grid' instead. It shows only one row, but that's something :) Now the question is... how to get it working with a listview. I'm using FF 3.6.

Comment: i would think that it may be because the ajax load hasn't returned yet when the view is rendered, but i think that in that case calling the load function from the console would load the data... from the docs: Important: loading is asynchronous! This call will return before the new data has been loaded. You shouldn't have to refresh the listiew in a load listener though... sorry I can't help more.

Comment: @Brandon - I should've checked that before really... The data is actually loaded correctly and is there on the page. However the listview is `<div class="x-list-body" style="height: 0px;"></div>` :( My elements are: `TabPanel (renderTo: body) > Panel > Listview`. Is there some way to fix the sizes?

Comment: oh, just make sure the height of all the elements is set high enough. height:123px. from the console can you Ext.getCmp('viewid').setHeight(200)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try with a store like this:

```
            store: objPlanManagerStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                autoLoad: true,
                proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                    url: '/your/url',
                    method: 'POST'
                }),
                reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
                    root: 'plans',
                    id: 'id',
                    fields: ['id', 'name', 'descr', 'tname', 'type', 'recurring']
                }),
                listeners: {
                    loadexception: function() {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Title', 'msg');
                    }
                }
            });
```

(just pasted from some of my code)

edit: thinking about it, the store doesn't seem to be the problem though.

Comment: Also requests the data properly, but I see no results. Exception window did not show up.

Comment: Accepted as answer. For real answer from Orbit, check the question comments.